# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL when returning a £ symbol using JSON

Tags: jquery, json

When I try to return a £ symbol from a JSON call, I get an error in chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
var currency = "";
var price = "";


$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '../JSONDeliveryPrice/',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    price = eval(data.price);
    currency = eval(data.currency);
  },
  async: false
});
console.log(price);
console.log(currency);
```

currency should equal "£" but instead I get that error. Do I have to encode/decode the value somehow? Also, price outputs correctly if I return just the price.

EDIT:

```
public virtual ActionResult JSONDeliveryPrice()
        {
            string currency = "£";
            decimal price = 123;            
            return Json(new { price = price, currency = currency }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us your JSON string please ?

Comment: I've edited my question to show the JSON string

Comment: Where? I can't see the pound symbol in your code.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff You still lacked to shows us the **JSON String**, all you did was show the code that **generates it**, please let us have the exact JSON that is been sent, use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for example, and don't use `eval()` when extracting the data out, what you can use is `var result = $.parseJSON(data);` at max, but never `eval()`

Comment: Hi, thanks, I solved it by not using eval();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `eval()` as you've already specified the data-type as JSON (jQuery will do the JSONifying for you. You can simply do:

```
...
success: function (data) {
    price = data.price;
    currency = data.currency;
},
...
```